# Web2Py Ajax request Too slow - Web2py View to Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, get, web2py

I have been using Web2py to Develop small scale applications. 
One of my application involves a table created using dataTables. There are buttons on the table and each has a dropdown with a few actions, which when clicked will update the status on the table.

My Problem is the GET request is taking a lot of time to respond, When the button is clicked it takes more than 15-20 seconds to get a response, and finally, reload the table. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDoh4.png)

I have done this using JS and Ajax.
Code for each item under the button

```
<a id="Details_btn"  class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="lead_statusupdate(this)" data-id="{{=lead.id}}" data-btn_status="Details Send" data-btn_user="{{=auth.user.id}}"><i class="fa fa-flag-checkered"> Details Send</i></a>
```

And this button calls to a Javascript within the HTML file
Code for JS

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      function lead_statusupdate(value) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        var leadno = $(value).data('id');
        var status = $(value).data('btn_status');
        var updater = $(value).data('btn_user');
        if (status !== "SMS Pending" && status !== "Mailer Pending"){
            var remarks = prompt("Please remarks related to your update:", "Daily Update");
            if (remarks == null || remarks == "") {
            remarks = "No remarks entered";}
            }
        $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/init/lead_entry/leadStatus_update',
              data: { view_leadno: leadno,
                       view_status: status,
                        view_updater: updater,
                         view_remarks: remarks
                    } 
            });
        $("#status_blck").load(" #status_blck > *");
        }
 </script>
```

The information from the view is passed to the Controller using GET and AJAX

On the controller side, the code is

```
@auth.requires(auth.has_membership('Sales_Staff') or auth.has_membership('Admin'))
def leadStatus_update():
    db.Lead_Status.insert(  lead_id=request.vars.view_leadno, 
                            lead_type='General Lead', 
                            status=request.vars.view_status, 
                            Updated_by=request.vars.view_updater, 
                            Remarks=request.vars.view_remarks)
    db(db.Fb_leads.id == request.vars.view_leadno).update(Final_Status=request.vars.view_status)
return response.json({'status':'success'})
```

I just need to send data to the controller to update the data on button click, any method can be used. The above method is one that was available to me after searching for looking around.

**EDIT:** changed the return from the controller function to return JSON and removed commit() for each action. Speed improved a bit ..not a great change!

Comment: There's no obvious reason why this should be slow, but the whole ajax part is probably a red herring.  How long does /init/lead_entry/leadStatus_update take to respond when you access it directly?  And how long do the equivalent SQL insert and update queries take to run if you run them directly on the database?

Comment: I made a loom video.. when i used the URL to do the GET fucntion..
 [link](https://www.loom.com/share/ec566cdec3b044ff804140e685568dd1)

Comment: Then I'd guess it's either a database issue, which you can test by running those queries against the database, or perhaps a webserver issue.  Is this the only function in the application which takes this long?